# Integrating RabbitMQ with Keycloak

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, rabbitmq, keycloak

I am experiencing issues when using Keycloak as the authorization service for RabbitMQ.

Here is what I have already done:

First, I created file named rabbitmq.config  like this:

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_oauth2]}
  ]},
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2, [
    {resource_server_id, <<"rabbitmq">>},
    {extra_scopes_source, <<"extra_scope">>},
    {preferred_username_claims, [<<"user_name">>]},
    {key_config, [
      {jwks_url, <<"http://0.0.0.0:8080:8080/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/certs">>}
    ]}
  ]}
].
```

And I move it to /etc/rabbitmq and restart rabbitmq server

After that, I run Keycloak server and create a realm named "test" in Keycloak and create 2 clients, one for the rabbit client which is an application will publish data of rabbitmq, and second is the rabbitmq itself as a resource server.

The rabbitmq client, I config it using client_creadential grant type and this is the json after decode access token:

```
{
  "exp": 1686908069,
  "iat": 1686907769,
  "jti": "db13bb2d-bb4f-40ea-ae19-8deaf8dfc4ce",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/test",
  "aud": "rabbitmq",
  "sub": "15f03347-e2fc-4f8c-9743-f4dfd59f67fe",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "mgt_api_client",
  "scope": "email rabbitmq.tag:management",
  "clientId": "mgt_api_client",
  "clientHost": "127.0.0.1",
  "email_verified": false,
  "clientAddress": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

This is the simple application based python I using to submit message to rabbitmq server for testing purpose:

```
import pika
import jwt
import datetime

connection_parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')


# Connect to RabbitMQ and create a channel
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connection_parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

# Declare the exchange

exchange_name = 'hungdeptrai'
channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange_name, exchange_type='direct', durable=True)
jwt_token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJHbmwyWmxiUmgzckFyNld5bWM5ODhfNWNZN1Q1R3VlUGQ1ZHBKbFhESlVrIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2ODY5MDgwNjksImlhdCI6MTY4NjkwNzc2OSwianRpIjoiZGIxM2JiMmQtYmI0Zi00MGVhLWFlMTktOGRlYWY4ZGZjNGNlIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL3JlYWxtcy90ZXN0IiwiYXVkIjoicmFiYml0bXEiLCJzdWIiOiIxNWYwMzM0Ny1lMmZjLTRmOGMtOTc0My1mNGRmZDU5ZjY3ZmUiLCJ0eXAiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJhenAiOiJtZ3RfYXBpX2NsaWVudCIsInNjb3BlIjoiZW1haWwgcmFiYml0bXEudGFnOm1hbmFnZW1lbnQiLCJjbGllbnRJZCI6Im1ndF9hcGlfY2xpZW50IiwiY2xpZW50SG9zdCI6IjEyNy4wLjAuMSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiY2xpZW50QWRkcmVzcyI6IjEyNy4wLjAuMSJ9.2FeD7Ba4hQGc__XfSX9PlUNR4-aauxl6TVjZOpTIkSNObPJ3O05b_W3ivEB9agzxPfrBhBRGb79OkIP8q3eWgXk7VYr93-BLRHtGQ_v9MrLOaKFHqZULT0F62-v57H_TD9LQ7MNRmRjUztpcUXI8_oSsThapiNuEMPHMJ6cmsv32kJ4GnxwDHUz7UQoFvnIIaqVejoTkLKQLN8wWA6uk3o8slUY2f9-smZTm8XQQfdwBNBKo0Np40nqY6B5Icxckqw_0owVQMW2ANoBVReunXpBod9dwUJuXUdNTu3BZANfHN886laO1VDLQunUfTdTg6VWQTP4qQ5Fs2Bm9a0ebQw"
# Publish the message
routing_key = 'my_queue'
message_body = 'Hello, World!'
message_properties = pika.BasicProperties(headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {jwt_token}'})

channel.basic_publish(exchange=exchange_name, routing_key=routing_key, body=message_body, properties=message_properties)

# Close the connection
connection.close()
```

But it always log error Access Refused. I don't know where is the problem here.